# La excepción de tarea nunca se recuperó

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws, asyncio

La cuestion es que necesito llamar a una lambda n cantidad de veces dependiendo de unos calculos que se hagan previamente y mandar ciertos parametros en base a esos calculos... No me importa el resultado de la otra lambda, solo me importa llamarla con los datos necesarios y la otra lambda ya manejo posibles errores. Eventualmente no puedo esperar a que la lambda termine un proceso, ya que estos pueden tomar minutos(Se que el maximo son 15min para AWS) pero al crear la tarea, se llama una vez, se ejecuta correctamente pero en eso me tira un error `Task exception was never retrieved`

```
import asyncio
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    asyncio.run(Settlement())
    return "Ok"

async def Settlement():
    #Hago calculos para los parametros de la lambda
    task = asyncio.create_task(invoker())

async def invoker():
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    for i in range(5):
        #Necesito llamar n cantidad de veces la lambda
        asyncio.create_task(client.invoke(
            FunctionName = '<ARN>',
            InvocationType = 'Event'
        ))
```

Comment: ¿Qué es boto3? ¿Qué hace client.invoke?

Comment: @CandidMoe boto3 es la libreria que uso para dynamo y la llamada a otra lambda... y el client.invoke es para invocar la otra lambda, la lambda hija, la que quiero que se quede ejecutandose

Comment: Si pudieras plantear tu pregunta con un código completo que no requiera recursos externos podría empezar a trabajar en ella.

Comment: @CandidMoe se me hace dificil no usar recursos externos, ya que el uso de dynamodb y la comunicacion a otra lambda requiere de boto3. Asyncio es el que utilizo para llamar a la lambda hija y que se quede ejecutandose. La verdad son los mínimos que necesito para explicar mi codigo